# Netlify is not deploying create-react-app

Tags: create-react-app, netlify, netlify-cli

Apparantly it takes 30 seconds to deploy a react app on netlify!

https://www.netlify.com/blog/2016/07/22/deploy-react-apps-in-less-than-30-seconds/

I have followed ***exactly*** the following steps :

```
create-react-app hello-world2
cd hello-world2
npm run build

npm install netlify-cli -g
netlify deploy
```

The CLI then gives me a bunch of options. I selected the "." for publish directory. Is that right?

This is what is in my console :

[image]

I then go to :

https://5ed0fcc54e316210489aa68c--hellowworld2.netlify.app/

and I get :

[image]

How is this possible if I am following the steps exactly?

Comment: So sorry. Just realised i did not read correctly. You have to specify "./build" when deploying. I will leave this question up incase anyone is as blind as me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create-React-App will build your app into production files that it places in the `./build` folder - see docs [here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/available-scripts#npm-run-build).

You need to tell Netlify to look in there, so set `publish directory` to `build`.